# mongoose populate returns null when added multiple fileds

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

**I am trying to use the populate method on a subcategory field and it is showing null. In my example, I want to populate the subcategory field.**
    [image: Get method]

[image: postMethod]

[image: Product Model]

[image: ProductCategory Model]
[image: ProductSubCategory Model]
[image: Result]

Comment: How can we reproduce the same problem with code in images?

Comment: I have tried using codes but it is not just working for me and its taking so much time

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question